# Why does jquery ui dialog mangle my jquery.tokeninput.js autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-tokeninput

I am using the snazzy jquery tokeninput plugin and jquery ui. When I display a form with a token input in it, rather than displaying the token input correctly, it loses some styling and splits into two input boxes. I've made a repro page (linked below) which mangles it.

Why is it doing it, and what can i do to fix it?

example repo html doc here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2808109/jquery%20dialog%20tokeninput%20demo.htm

edit: have found the answer

Comment: may i request u to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141176/facebook-style-jquery-tokeninput-script-retains-value-in-the-jquery-ui-modal-win regarding tokeninput and modal window issue... is such request considered valid in SOF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like dialog re-runs the script tags in the block of code so my autocomplete is executing twice.

my fix was to remove the script tags in the code I was dialoging

```
$("#popup script").remove();
$("#popup").dialog({ ... });
```