# TokenInput plus jQuery UI Dialog conflict

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

**UPDATE** This seems to no longer be an issue in latest Fx/Chrome using edge jQuery

---

**PROBLEM**: The autocomplete will be behind the dialog and if you move it, the dialog will move outside the page.

**Investigation**

I have already checked

[Why does jquery ui dialog mangle my jquery.tokeninput.js autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669654/why-does-jquery-ui-dialog-mangle-my-jquery-tokeninput-js-autocomplete)

And read github requests

- issue 93 [Result list doesn't display properly when in jQuery-ui modal dialog](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/93) and
- issue 94 [Dropdown positioning issues](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/94)

but I still have the same issues with what I believe are the latest of everything (TokenInput JS and CSS from github [jQuery TokenInput](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)).

---

**DEMOS AND CODE**

- [DEMO1](http://plungjan.name/test/filter_no_ui.html): how TokenInput works when jQuery UI is commented out
- [DEMO2](http://plungjan.name/test/filter.html): what I want to have working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet"        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />

<button id="filterBut">FILTER</button>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Filter" style="border:1px solid black">
    <p class="validateTips">Enter text contained in the respective fields</p>

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Field1</label><br/><input type="text" name="Flt1" id="Flt1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:300px"/><br/><br/>
        <label for="email">Field2</label><br/><input type="text" name="Flt2" id="Flt2" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:300px" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {  
   $("#Flt1, #Flt2").tokenInput([
      {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
      {id: 11, name: "Python"},
      {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
      {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
      {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
      {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
      {id: 29, name: "C#"},
      {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
      {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
      {id: 41, name: "C"},
      {id: 43, name: "C++"},
      {id: 47, name: "Java"}
    ],{theme:"facebook"});

  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 460,
            modal: true
  });                        
  $( "#filterBut" ).click(function() {

  // suggestion from 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669654/why-does-jquery-ui-dialog-mangle-my-jquery-tokeninput-js-autocomplete
    $("#dialog-form script").remove();
  // does not seem to change anything


    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });

});
</script>         
              </div>     
            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of this library (issue #94 on [github](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)). You can collect the patched files from [here](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/94/files) to fix the issue.

Comment: Patch files from issue # 94 fixes the issue of not showing the dropdown. However, it show a vertical scrollbar on the ui dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Change style en css for div.token-input-dropdown and replaze z-index:1 with z-index:1005.

Comment: Problem is no longer there. Thanks for the input

Comment: This is the real answer

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your HTML a bit and seems like setting zindex:1005 shows the dropdown over the dialog.

```
 ],{theme:"facebook", zindex:1005});
```

However, if you move the dialog, the autocomplete dropdown stays on the previous position.

Comment: Great - I cannot test this until mid September so it may take a while to see if what you suggest works

Comment: I have uploaded the code [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/c8ewt0pa0.html) for you to test.

Comment: Thanks - in FX15 OSX, the field becomes short when I type in it and the suggestions are transparent. It seems to work better in Chrome also OSX

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery code solves the hiding problem for me (thanks @user2192014 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11613362/304209) for the idea):

```
$(".token-input-dropdown-facebook, .token-input-list-facebook").css("z-index","9999");
```